# Close push menu on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I go about closing a push canvas menu when the use scrolls? or clicks off of it.

Below is the HTML and Jquery. Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
  $nav_list = $('#nav_list');

  $nav_list.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
    $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
  <div class="menu-primary-container">

    <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/creative/">Creative</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/online/">Online</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/print/">Print</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/the-studio/">The Studio</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/work/">Our Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/snippets/">Snippets</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/blog/">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://10.0.0.127:8888/page16-sass/contact/">Get in touch</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>  

  <div class="mobile-phone">01268 271 858</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: could you please share the required CSS too. Will be easy to reproduce the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

toggle your pushmenu classes on scroll.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    $('.pushmenu-push').removeClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
    $menuLeft.removeClass('pushmenu-open');
});
```

you might want to add timer to prevent the menu from scrolling if the user accidentally scrolls before choosing a menu item (could happen on touch devices).